# How can I fake my own in App Tiles in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am considering my Launch Screen/Dashboard screen having tiles(Squares with a few lines of information on them). I understand that tiles are not a UI object for use inside Windows Phone apps, but I've seen some people fake them somehow.

Can anybody gimme and some tips and guidance as to how this is achieved? I am under the impression of what I have seen in my first 2 days working on Win-Mobile that you cannot stack view objects on top of each other. For example drawing a square object and then drawing 3 lines of text on top of that to make a tile.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Do you want to fake the tiles in your own app or you would like to put tiles out to the main screen of Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I am doing for my Dashboard page in my application. It is simply a StackPanel with two TextBlocks inside. These StackPanels are then inside of a WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone inside of a ListBox, which you don't have to use.

```
<ListBox Name="lstTiles" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="173" Height="173" Margin="12,12,0,0" Tap="stkSignIn_Tap">
            <TextBlock Text="Tile Title" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,6,12,12" Height="106" />
            <TextBlock Text="Your subtitle here" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="173" Height="173" Margin="12,12,0,0" Tap="stkSignIn_Tap">
            <TextBlock Text="Tile Title" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,6,12,12" Height="106" />
            <TextBlock Text="Your subtitle here" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="173" Height="173" Margin="12,12,0,0" Tap="stkSignIn_Tap">
            <TextBlock Text="Tile Title" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,6,12,12" Height="106" />
            <TextBlock Text="Your subtitle here" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Was it the [HubTile control](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-HubTile-in-depth-Part1-key-concepts-and-API) you saw?

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik RADHubTile control can do this for you. Please, check out this article:

[New Hub Tile Control for Your Windows Phone Apps](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/12-03-22/new-hub-tile-control-for-your-windows-phone-apps.aspx)

Note: the library cost around $99 I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tile controls available now, but for the sake of anyone else going in search of one, you can find my pretty simple 'home grown' tile control here: http://www.crisrowlands.com/wpdev-tips-4/